# how many times an number digit is shown on user integer input

Tags: java

the project I need to do is:

- get an integer number from user (Done)
- check how many times the same digit is shown on this number.(??)
- give an output of how many time each digit is shown.

so I couldn't seem to resolve this, any help??

(a friend advised "for" loop, but sadly I don't know how to use it in this task.)

Thanks ahead.

meanwhile I have this:

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
      public class HW1 
      {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
         {

              Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
              int count, digit, number;
              System.out.println("Enter a positive integer number: ");
              number=input.nextInt();
```

Comment: @fahrbach so, never heard of `long` or `BigInteger`?

Comment: Convert Integer to String and do an iteration over the String to count digits... ?!

Comment: Did you read your school book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an assignment I believe you have to do it in a very particular matter, so I guess it is a must for you to convert the input from String to Integer, then count.

To count convert your integer back to a String then count how many instances of each digit exist.

We know that the digits in base 10 are: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

So create variables for them. Ideally you would use an array but you can figure that out yourself as an extra. These will keep track of how many instances of each digit there are:

```
int zero, one, two, three, four, .... nine;
```

Convert your integer back to String:

```
String s = number + "";
```

Then use a for loop to traverse the String and count the instances of each digit.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if(s.charAt(i) == '0')
       zero++;

    else if(s.charAt(i) == '1')
       one++;

    else if(s.charAt(i) == '2')
       two++;

    . . .
    // You do the rest.
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! you helped a lot!! appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
      public class HW1 
      {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          int digit, number;
          int[] count=new int[10];
          System.out.println("Enter a positive integer number: ");
          number=input.nextInt();
          while(number>0)
          {              
              digit=number%10;
              switch(digit)
              -{
              case 0:
              count[0]++;
              break;
              case 1:
              count[1]++;
              break;
              .....
              ......
              ........
              case 9:
              count[9]++;
              break;
              default:
               }
              number=number/10;
           }
           for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
           {
            system.out.println("digit "+i+ "occurs "+count[i]+"times");
           }
             }
```

Hope it will produce the expected output.....

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int digit, number;
      int[] count=new int[10];
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer number: ");
      number=input.nextInt();
      while(number>0)
      {              
          digit=number%10;
          count[digit]++;
          number=number/10;
       }
       for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
       {
        system.out.println("digit "+i+ "occurs "+count[i]+"times");
       }
         }
```